# Android: Custom Image List

Tags: java, android

What I have to do is to simply open an activity which was mentioned in list activity example: In this List activity I have a name of three restaurants and when I clicked each it will generate a toast that you clicked this restaurant, but what I want to do is to click restaurant name and it will open that restaurant's activity.

This is MainActivity.java Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lv;
Context context;

ArrayList prgmName;
public static int [] prgmImages={

        R.drawable.images1,
        R.drawable.images2,
        R.drawable.images3,
        R.drawable.images4};
public static String [] prgmNameList={"Red Apple","Arizona Grill","Bumzees"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context=this;

    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList,prgmImages));

}



}
```

CustomAdapter.java :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
String [] result;
Context context;
int [] imageId;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=prgmNameList;
    context=mainActivity;
    imageId=prgmImages;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program, null);
    holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
```

}

Xml Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="25dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:text=" Reservations" />

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

program.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.abdul.reservation" >

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you create the Toast in the adapter (inside the clicklistener for the rowview) just change to startActivity to open the restaurant activity.

Code to open new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, RestaurantActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

If you can't use `context` directly just use it to call `getApplicationContext()`

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) for more info on how to use startActivity.

Comment: What is RestaurantActivity.class, is it a java class or an activity in your suggested code and which code should i use in this class or activity.

Comment: `RestaurantActivity.class` is the class where you define the Restaurant activity that you said you wanted to open. The code you should use is whatever you need to show your restaurant details.

Comment: its ok but when i apply this code on my CustomAdapter.java in clicklistner just after toast it will give an error.

Comment: And how can i implement my 3 restaurants activity in just one class (RestaurantActivity.class)?

Comment: Updated the code to use context, see if that was the error. Regarding how to build the Restaurant Activity, I think you should really take a look in [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) and do some tutorials to understand the basics of Android Programming.